# Javascript function in between a <script> tag is not getting loaded on an ajax call

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

As part of an ajax call I want to add this javascript function listed between a script tag to my document. The ajax call works fine except it cuts out this portion of my document.

```
<script language="javascript"> 

    window.onload = function(){


            var input = document.getElementById('tid-acc');


            document.getElementById('rule-type').onchange = function() { 
               var v

al = this.value; 
           if (val == 'tid and acc') {
               input.style.display = 'inline'; 
           }
           else {
              input.style.display = 'none';
           }
        };
    }
    </script>
```

What am I doing wrong? For reason I won't go into, I need to execute this function dynamically on Ajax call. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show us your ajax code that is used to retrieve and run this javascript.

Comment: Is this script a response received from your ajax call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a good article about it: [Global eval. What are the options?](http://perfectionkills.com/global-eval-what-are-the-options/)

Article also compares how famous js libraries do it:

> Global eval in libraries
>
> So what do some of the popular Javascript libraries do? Which global
>   eval solution do they chose?
>
> As we’ve seen earlier, jQuery sacrifices return value for a more
>   extensive browser support, using script insertion technique in its
>   jQuery.globalEval method.
>
> Prototype.js doesn’t even try to evaluate scripts globally — it uses a
>   good old, direct eval invocation. Instead, Prototype.js warns about
>   ramification of local execution in the documentation.
>
> Dojo choses the infamous window.eval variation, but does something
>   really messed up — it uses indirect eval if eval exists on a global
>   object (which should be true in all ES3-compliant browsers), and falls
>   back on regular eval invocation. This kind of fall back obviously
>   results in code executed locally, which should also happen silently.
>   Dojo’s eval behavior will vary wildly depending on the environment,
>   and has a possibility of uncaught error. On a related, humorous note,
>   I was just as stunned by comments around dojo.eval as David Mark in
>   this message.
>
> Mootools uses window.execScript when present, falling back on script
>   insertion (similar to jQuery). jQuery’s script insertion, however, is
>   more robust than Mootools, as they actually test if it results in
>   evaluation of code.
>
> Fuse.js choses a very elaborate and careful strategy. It tests if
>   indirect eval works as expected (catching an error if any), uses it if
>   it does; if indirect eval is defunct, Fuse falls back on script
>   injection. Unlike jQuery or Mootools, it actually tries to return a
>   value of a code executed via script injection. It does so by wrapping
>   contents of code with eval. An interesting side effect of executing
>   code globally via eval is that function and variable declarations
>   create deletable bindings (which is most likely an insignificant
>   detail).

Here is how Mootools 1.3.2 does it:

```
String.implement('stripScripts', function(exec){
    var scripts = '';
    var text = this.replace(/<script[^>]*>([\s\S]*?)<\/script>/gi, function(all, code){
        scripts += code + '\n';
        return '';
    });
    if (exec === true) Browser.exec(scripts);
    else if (typeOf(exec) == 'function') exec(scripts, text);
    return text;
});

Browser.exec = function(text){
    if (!text) return text;
    if (window.execScript){
        window.execScript(text);
    } else {
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
        script.text = text;
        document.head.appendChild(script);
        document.head.removeChild(script);
    }
    return text;
};

// on successful HTML request
success: function(text){
    response.html = text.stripScripts(function(script){
        response.javascript = script;
    });
}
```